# Questions around the Beginning Parts of the Proof: $B \subseteq A$ iff $A \cup B = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have a question about the beginning of this proof.

The proof I am going through starts out like this:

Suppose $B \subseteq A$ and let $x \in (A \cup B)$. Then $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. [Proof continues from here...]

**Question 1:** Are we allowed to let x be an element of something not in our initial assumptions? We have $B \subseteq A$ as an assumption, not $x \in (A \cup B)$. But then we say let $x \in (A \cup B)$. Is that allowed?

If it is fine to let x be an element of something not in our initial assumption, then we have both $x \in ( B \subseteq A$) and $x \in (A \cup B)$

**Question 2:** Are these the same x's or are these two different x's? In other words is this: $x \in ( B \subseteq A$) and $y \in (A \cup B)$, where $x \neq$ y? Or is it $x \in ( B \subseteq A$) and $x \in (A \cup B)$, where the x's are the same? I am trying to understand if we are overloading the x term with two different meanings, or if these x terms mean the same thing.

Comment: When you say $x \in (A \subseteq B)$, do you mean $x \in A$ and $A \subseteq B$?  Or are you thinking of $A \subseteq B$ as a set, which happens to contain an element $x$?

Comment: I made a typo, I mean $x \in $($B \subseteq A$) and by that I mean $\forall x (x \in B \rightarrow x \in A)$

Comment: The *definition* of equality between two sets $A$ and $B$ is that $A=B$ if $x \in A$ implies $x\in B$ and $x \in B$ implies $x \in A$

Comment: I will point out that by assuming $x\in A$ you are tacitly (*i.e. without saying it aloud or explicitly*) also assuming that $A$ is non-empty.  This doesn't cause issues all the time, but it is important to recognize that it is still an assumption that if ignored leads to false statements such as "For all sets $A,B,X,Y$ you have $(A\times X) = (B\times Y) \iff A=B$ and $X=Y$."  (*The statement can be made true by asserting that $A,B,X,Y$ must all be non-empty but is false otherwise since $\emptyset\times \{1\}=\emptyset\times \{2\}$ for example*).

Comment: OK, so if you mean $\forall x (x \in B \to x \in A)$, the way to write that is $B \subseteq A$, not  $x \in (B \subseteq A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're reading is a very common proof pattern when showing that sets are equal.

What makes a set is the elements it contains.  So to show two sets are equal, we need to show that they contain exactly the same elements.  That is, every element of the first is an element of the second, and every element of the second is also an element of the first.

> **Question 1:** Are we allowed to let x be an element of something not in our initial assumptions? We have $B \subseteq A$ as an assumption, not $x \in (A \cup B)$. But then we say let $x \in (A \cup B)$. Is that allowed?

You're right, the initial assumption is that $B \subset A$.  You're not assuming that a specific element $x$ is in $A \cup B$.  Instead, you are pointing to an arbitrary element of $A \cup B$ and naming it $x$. The proof proceeds to show that $x$ (whatever it is) is also in $A$.

> **Question 2:** Are these the same x's or are these two different x's?

Once you pick an element and name it $x$, you can't name another element $x$.  You want to show that if $x \in A \cup B$ then $x \in A$ (the same $x$).

Comment: Just for clarification (as I am re-writing this proof in a way that I understand). We can start with the given assumptions, but it is also fine for us to "suppose" things outside of those initial assumptions? More concretely, it is allowed to do this: we are given $x \in (B \subseteq A)$. But now we can also assume outside of the assumption another thing like: $y \in (A \cup B)$ . But we have to make it clear that $x \neq y$. Is that correct understanding?

Comment: The reason I ask about term overloading is because one of my arguments hinges on using the assumption $B \subseteq A$. If you say $y \in B \subseteq A$, then suppose $x \in (A \cup B)$. Then say this means $x \in A$ or $x \in B$, and then consider the case $x \in B$, you then can't say by the assumption $B \subseteq A$ that $x \in A$, because $y \in B \subseteq A$ and x $\neq y$ here.

Comment: @tree_traversal I am still confused by what you *think* you mean by "$x\in (B\subseteq A)$."  The statement "$(B\subseteq A)$" is either a true or a false statement.  What do you mean by $x\in \text{True}$ or by $x\in \text{False}$?  Perhaps you mean to write $x\in B$ and $B\subseteq A$, but then what purpose does your $x\in B$ serve in your proof?  You never use it later in the proof so why bother assuming it at all?

Comment: @tree_traversal As for "can you make assumptions both at the start *and* later as well?"  The answer is of course *Yes!*  Though, if you *do* make such an assumption you may need to explore the alternative as well.  Further, if you assume $a\in A$ and later in the proof assume $b\in B$, you do *not* need to assert that $a\neq b$ since they could be the same, though you are open to the possibility that they could be the same or could be different.

Comment: @JMoravitz, the book defines $B \subseteq A$ to mean $\forall x(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$. I suppose it means what you said, $x \in B$ and B $\subseteq$ A.

Comment: @tree_traversal based on our discussion under the question I think you're writing $x \in (B \subseteq A)$ when you really mean to write just $B \subseteq A$.   There's no need for an x in that statement.

Comment: As for the extra assumptions question, you are trying to show $A \cup B \subseteq A$.  At no point do you assert that $x \in A \cup B$ on its own (indeed, the set could be empty).  Instead, you show that $x \in B$ is necessary whenever $x \in A \cup B$ happens to be true.  So you assume (temporarily) $x \in A \cup B$ and show that $x \in A$ follows.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, do I not need to pick an arbitrary but specific x in $B \subseteq A$? The crux of my question is related to this. Assumption: $B \subseteq A$. Let $x \in (A \cup B)$. Either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. Let's consider the case $x \in B$. Given the assumption $B \subseteq A$ we have $x \in A$. I am very suspicious  if this works, due to the "term overloading question". Is the x that I let be in $A \cup B$ the same x in $B \subseteq A$?

Comment: @tree_traversal: Yes, it is the same $x$.

Comment: That makes sense! The take away here is I can start with givens and then also introduce new "assumptions", but I want to do it in a way that will lead to the conclusion of the proof I am looking for. Thanks for your help.